# Using $filter for integer (1, -1) in angularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have problems getting length of array-elements with specified attribute using `$filter`. the attribute `state` can be `0`, `1` and `-1`. I get sub-arrays with `$filter` and then check `length`. It wont work with `state = 1`. It seems that the filter also takes elements with `state = -1`. Is this a bug or do I need to set the filter differently?

I provided a snippet to show the effekt. Thanks in advance.

```js
angular.module ('app', []).controller ('ctrl', function ($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.data = [
    { state: 0 },
    { state: 1 },
    { state: -1 }
  ];
  
  $scope.out1 = $filter ('filter')($scope.data, { state: 0 }).length;  // =1
  $scope.out2 = $filter ('filter')($scope.data, { state: 1 }).length;  // =2 <== THATS NOT RIGHT
  $scope.out3 = $filter ('filter')($scope.data, { state: -1 }).length; // =1
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div>Elements with state=0 --> <strong ng-bind="out1"></strong></div>
  <div>Elements with state=1 --> <strong ng-bind="out2"></strong></div>
  <div>Elements with state=-1 --> <strong ng-bind="out3"></strong></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think it treats it like a **string**, for example `<div ng-repeat="x in data | filter:{'state':1}"> {{x}} </div>` will give you states `-1` and `1`, both containing `1` as the filter specified. Maybe you need a custom filter, checking for the numerical values

Comment: @AlekseySolovey That is what I was thinking to. Isn't there a way to search for literal instead of containing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS treats `state` values as strings(`"-1".indexOf("1") != -1`), so just add additional third `strict` argument to `filter`:

```
$scope.out2 = $filter('filter')($scope.data, { state: 1 }, true).length;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what i was looking for. Can't believe i didn't saw that in the docs.

Comment: Would you mind upvoting my question for student-badge's sake? ;)